# Single cryptic crossword clue: one beer... [8]

Tags: cryptic-clues

This is a single cryptic crossword clue. The clue is the clue and not this preamble.

> One beer at German festival for relative genius [8]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is hardly cryptic, if you know how British crosswords work...

> Einstein
>
> "German festival" suggests beer steins, a common sight, and more-or-less a trope to non-Germans. "One beer" would be "**ein** Bier" in German, but it could also be "one stein (of beer)", or "**ein Stein**". The "relative genius" clinches it; Albert **Einstein** was unquestionably a genius, and is best known for his Theory of **Relativ**ity.

Comment: do you want to explain your reasoning?

Comment: Added behind the spoiler

Comment: hardly cryptic because too easy?

Comment: thanks for adding the explanation to the answer - made it complete.

Comment: More or less too easy, yes... I'm lousy at British crosswords (I do American puzzles), and it took me less than a second after reading the clue to get the answer.

Comment: There's a place for easy clues. I am often chided for making my puzzles too hard.

Comment: Jeff, I think the thing is in British crosswords they hide things pretty well and can be pretty obscure, but the principles of the 'cryptic clue' are that there are several different things that point to the same word in the clue so that when you get a clue you know it is correct because  it fits in multiple ways... so although this is an 'easy' one for you, it is 'cryptic' because of the structure.

Comment: @tom - Also note that anyone with even a beginner's knowledge of German would get this super quickly as well.  Perhaps if you said "A drink at a German festival..."